# Unexpected token private

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Whenever I add the contructor(private http:Http) to the code, it gives the error. Any idea?

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MultipleErrors: app/services/loginService:7:15: Unexpected token private
app/services/loginService:7:23: Unexpected token http
app/services/loginService:7:27: Unexpected token :
app/services/loginService:7:29: Semi-colon expected
app/services/loginService:7:33: Semi-colon expected
app/services/loginService:7:33: Unexpected token )
app/services/loginService:7:35: Semi-colon expected
app/services/loginService:26:16: Semi-colon expected
app/services/loginService:32:17: Semi-colon expected
app/services/loginService:36:1: Unexpected token End of File
```

loginService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
 constructor (private http: Http) {}
  //tet
  /*
  login(path:string, username:string, password:string) {
    var creds = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/sessions/create', creds, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.saveToLocal(data),
        err => this.logError(err),
        () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
      );

    return this.http.get(path);
  }*/
  saveToLocal(jwt) {
    if (jwt) {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', jwt)
    }
  }

  logError(err) {
    console.error('There was an error: ' + err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you use ES6 instead of TypeScript. ES6 doesn't support this (visibility with private / public and types) and will throw such errors.

With ES6, you can only use this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor (http) {}

  (...)
}
```

Moreover for dependency injection, with ES6, you need to add a static getter for the `parameters` property:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor (http) {}

  (...)

  static getter parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Thierry, however, the code is not working for my case, ES6. I guess getter is for ES7?  I end up doing like this, export class LoginService {

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }
  http:Http;
  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
    console.log('http', http);
  }

Comment: Yes you don't have support of `private` in ES6 ;-) If you use Ionic2, you could use the --ts option when generating projects to be able to use TypeScript...

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using Ionic2. If I want to use ts, do I have to recreate the project from any seed with gulp+ts?

Comment: Thierry, I grabbed the seed project from github. Thanks